# Assignment operator and side effects with sequence points

Tags: c, c99, conditional-operator

I'm looking for some clarification for the emphasised line.

> (C99 6.5.16/3) An assignment operator stores a value in the object
>   designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value
>   of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue. The
>   type of an assignment expression is the type of the left operand
>   unless the left operand has qualified type, in which case it is the
>   unqualified version of the type of the left operand. **The side effect
>   of updating the stored value of the left operand shall occur between
>   the previous and the next sequence point.**

Consider the following example:

```
int x = 42;
int y = 0;

int main()
{
   // side effect of modifying 'x'
   x = y;
}
```

What are the previous and next sequence point? Is there a sequence point at the start of main?

Comment: These are declarations. IIRC an initialisation value given during a declaration does not count as a declaration.

Comment: The point of the sentence is a situation like `x = (y = z);`, where storing the value in `y` may happen before or after storing the value in `x`. But in `x = (y = z) && foo();`, there is a sequence point at the `&&` [after the evaluation of its left operand, more precisely], so the value must be stored in `y` before `foo()` is called (if at all) or the result of `(y = z) && foo()` is stored in `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.1.2.3 defines sequence points as the places by which all side effects of the previous evaluations have taken place and the side effect of subsequent evaluations have not yet started taking place. The annex C of the standard defines the places where the sequence points take place: function calls, end of logical operators, the comma operator, and the ternary operator, end of a full declarations, end of a full expression, and so on.

In this case, the previous sequence point is the start of `main()`, and the next sequence point is the semicolon at the end of the assignment. At the first sequence point, `x` will have a value of 42, and at the second one, it will be 0.

Comment: Is there possibly a case which violates this? I mean how can the side effect of updating the stored value can occur outside of given sequence points?

Comment: It cannot, but there can be problems if you try to use the new value before it is known to be stored. The classic is `x = ++x + x++;`, which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation about sequence points from the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

In this case, the sequence points are just before and after the full expression `x = y;`.

Comment: C FAQ doesn't say `main` i.e. start of program is a sequence point.

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, the given informal definition "a point where everything is settled" seems reasonable for the start of a program. Also, `main` is a function and is at some point called by your operating system. You could argue that there is a sequence point during this call. Yes, this is a bit far fetched. I will try to find which part of the standard the faq refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to user4815162342's answer, too long for a comment. Statements are sequenced:

> A statement specifies an action to be performed. Except as indicated,
>   statements are executed in sequence.

So as a rule of thumb you have a sequence point at every `;`, though they are not mentioned explicitly as such in the standard.